# Approach to solve a coupled system of PDE (heat transfer in cylindrical coordinates)

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, mp.mathematical-physics, linear-pde, laplacian, heat-equation

I have the following two PDEs, which describe steady-state coupled heat transport between an externally heated axisymmetric solid body (Eq. 1, $T(r,z)$) and a fluid (Eq. 2, $t(z)$) flowing inside it:

$$
\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial r^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial T}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial z^2}=0 \tag1
$$

$$
\frac{\partial t}{\partial z}+\alpha(t-T)=0 \tag2
$$
Eq. (1) is defined in the domain $r\in[r_1,r_2]$ where $r_1$ and $r_2$ describe the inner and outer radii of the cylinder and $z\in[0,L]$ where $L$ is the length of the cylinder. The boundary conditions for Eq. (1) are:
$$
\frac{\partial T(r,0)}{\partial z}=\frac{\partial T(r,L)}{\partial z}=0 \tag3
$$
$$
\frac{\partial T(r_2,z)}{\partial r}=\gamma \tag4
$$
$$
\frac{\partial T(r_1,z)}{\partial r}=\beta(T(r_1,z)-t) \tag5
$$
For Eq. (2) it is known that $t(z=0)=t_{\mathrm{in}}$

$\alpha, \beta, \gamma, t_{\mathrm{in}}$ are known constants. It seems the solid and fluid temperatures are coupled through the boundary condition at $r=r_1$ (solid-fluid interface, Robin condition).

I know that I can express $(2)$ as:
$$
\frac{\partial t}{\partial z} + \alpha (t - T(r,z))=0 \Rightarrow t=e^{-\alpha z}\int e^{\alpha z} T(r,z) \mathrm{d}z \\ \Rightarrow t=\alpha e^{-\alpha z} \Bigg[\int_0^z e^{\alpha s}T(r,s)\mathrm{d}s+\frac{t_{in}}{\alpha}\Bigg]
$$
This can be substituted in $(5)$ to get a bc only in terms of $(T)$. But I have no idea how to handle such integral type condition.

Any suggestion on how to approach this problem analytically is appreciated.